# Finding minimum value using nodes and null

Tags: java, minimum

was just wondering how I should interpret this code?, the thing thats throwing me off the most is the minOfTail = next.minVal() part, and when we compare thisNumber to minOfTail, what exactly is the value given to that variable minOfTail?

```java
    public ListOfNVersion03PartB(int num)
    {
        thisNumber = num;
        next = null;

        ++nodeCount;
        nodeID = nodeCount;

    }
```

```java
 public int minVal()
    {
        int minOfTail;

        if ( next == null )
            return thisNumber;

        minOfTail = next.minVal();

        if ( thisNumber <= minOfTail )
            return thisNumber; 
        else
            return minOfTail;

    } // method minVal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function recursively computes the minimum value of the `thisNumber` in a linked list of objects. Function `minVal()` computes the minimum value among the tail of the list that starts at the current object.

If the `next` field of the current object is `null` then that tail is exactly that object and the minimum value of the tail starting at the current object is just `thisNumber`.

If the `next field is not`null` then the minimum value of the tail starting at the current object is the minimum of

- the `thisNumber` value of the current value and
- the minimum of the tail starting at the next object.

To the function first finds the minimum value of the tail starting at the next object and assigns that value to `minOfTail`. Then it returns the minimum value of `minOfTail` and `thisNumber` of the current object.

Comment: Hi sorry if I missed something, but could you clarify if my interpretation on this is correct

```java

        minOfTail = next.minVal();

        if ( thisNumber <= minOfTail )
```
minOfTail keeps searching for the value of the next object and thisNumber is sort of like a placeholder?

and thanks for explaining above, I do understand it a lot better.

Comment: No, I don't think that is correct. `thisNumber` is not a placeholder. It is the value stored in the object on which the `minValue()` method is invoked. `minOfTail` is set to the minimum value of the objects that follow (in the list). What you see here is basically this loop: `result = Integer.MAX_VALUE; while (object != null) { result = Math.min(result, object.thisNumber); object = object.next; }`. The loop is not written explicitly but as a recursive function. You may want to look up recursion and loops in some programming handbook.

Answer (score 1):

> was just wondering how I should interpret this code?

This question is too broad and cannot be answered.

> the thing thats throwing me off the most is the minOfTail = next.minVal() part

This can be answered.

So, the entire `minVal()` function can be rewritten as follows:

```
public int minVal()
{
    if ( next == null )
        return thisNumber;
    return Math.min( thisNumber, next.minVal() );
}
```

Or even like this:

```
public int minVal()
{
    return next == null?  thisNumber : Math.min( thisNumber, next.minVal() );
}
```

So, `next.minVal()` will simply invoke the `next` node to calculate its own minimum value, and the next node will delegate to its own next node, and so on until there is no next node.

Please also note that this:

```
    int minOfTail;

    ... unrelated code here...

    minOfTail = next.minVal();
```

is ancient C style (C style before C compilers started being influenced by C++) it is not common at all in Java, it is not wise to do in any language, and it is generally frowned upon in the modern day.

Comment: cheers bro, just doing some uni work and im a complete beginner so this was very helpful :-)